# Required validation in File upload in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I want to make file upload field required, I have done all the other validations on upload ActionResult but the required is not working
Here is my code (I want to do all the validation in ActionResult not in Model using [Required])

```
    public ActionResult Create([Video video, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> URL)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    foreach (var file in URL)    
                      **if (file.ContentLength == 0)**
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("URL", "URL is required");
                            return View();
                        }
                    ........
                 }
             }
```

Please let me know where I am doing it wrong